# How can I only show the current book on book navigation?

Tags: 8, navigation

I have a list of books and I would only like to see the current book on the book navigation. How can I achieve that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your Drupal version?

Comment: For Drupal 7, [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/61046/how-to-create-a-menu-for-current-book) question might help you.

Comment: @VictorF so it's not possible with Drupal 8?

Comment: I haven't found any module yet, but it is probably possible with some kind of custom solution.

Comment: @VictorF I tried  ` if (!$('#block-booknavigation .block-inner nav ul li').hasClass('active')){
 $(this).hide();
}` but it didn't work. Do you have any suggestions?Thanks!